# Clicking a specific link by class name

Tags: javascript, html, class

I am trying to click a specific link but both have the same class name.
Here is a sample HTML code:

```
<a href= "sample link" class= "test class" </a>
<a href= "sample link2" class= "test class" </a>
```

Here is the javascript I am using:

```
document.getElementsByClassName("test class").click();
```

How would I make sure it clicks the first sample link instead of sample link2?

Comment: How will you decide which link to trigger the click?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
document.getElementsByClassName("test class")[0].click();
```

Answer (score 5):

You can use:

```
document.getElementsByClassName("test class")[0].click();
```

Answer (score 1):

`getElementsByClassName` returns a node list, so you can use `getElementsByClassName("test class")[0]` to access only the first element.

```
document.getElementsByClassName("test class")[0].click();
```

Answer (score 0):

a jQuery solution is something like

```
$(".test_class").filter('a[href=="link2"]').trigger("click");
```

Vanilla js could do it as well, but it would take more code. If you're not looking to cut performance times to the bare minimum, jQuery will do most of the hard stuff in this case.

Comment: the other solutions will work, but only if the page structure never changes. Definitely appropriate solutions in a static page.